# Use reversed unique IDs in Mongo DB for better performance?

Tags: mongodb

I have a big mass of IDs that begin with the same prefix. Does it make sense to reverse the IDs for better performance?

For example when I have this datetime-based IDs:

```
2016-01-02_15:01:23.001-a
2016-01-02_15:01:23.001-b
2016-01-02_15:01:23.001-c
...
```

I would assume that the following IDs with reversed parts

```
a-001.23:01:15_02-01-2016
b-001.23:01:15_02-01-2016
c-001.23:01:15_02-01-2016
```

should be the better solution because mongo begins parsing IDs on the left.

Right?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, if ids are strings, it will boost performance sooner process discover ids are not same. But... string types are not performant as compared to numbers. You could store dates to their numeric counterparts. e.g. epoch time or even timestamp.

Comment: You might rather consider a compound id, consisting of multiple fields.

Comment: This really depends on what you are using the data and how you use it, as well as what your consideration of "performance" actually is. For instace a "date prefix" is very useful when looking for documents within a given "Date Range", and the same can be said for any other type of "prefix". On the other hand, using a different or more "randomized" prefix component is one principle used with "sharding" in order to purposely "distribute" data for performance reasons. It's really all to broad a subject for discussion here. Do what works best for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you all for the comments. Very helpful!